# Call fnGetData() on a variable table name

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to make a call like this:

```
var table1 = $('#table1').dataTable();
var table1 = $('#table2').dataTable();

function action(tableId){
      tableId.fnGetData(#elem);
      ...
      return;
}
```

And if i make the call with the id like: `action(table1);`
I get the following error `tableId.fnGetData is not a function`

Comment: looks more of syntax error

Comment: `$(tableId).fnGetData` ?

Comment: I get $(...).fnGetData is not a function

Comment: which plugin are you using?

Comment: Yes It is a syntax error because It should make the call with table1.fnGetData(#elem) instead of tableId.fnGetData(#elem)

Comment: The plugins is Datatable and everythings working I'm just trying to make it generic because I don't want to write code for every table

Comment: can you share the link of that datatable plugin?

Comment: http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js

Comment: I am not able to see `fnGetData` method in this link https://datatables.net/reference/api/ Are you sure you are calling right method?

Comment: Yes I'm sure because as i said when i call it directly without cariable use it works :)

Comment: Can you share the other relevant code like what is working and how are you calling it otherwise? fiddle would help  http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be calling `fnGetData()` on the `dataTable` object. Make sure you do so.

E.g. this should work fine:

```
var table1 = $('#table2').dataTable();
table1.fnGetData($('#elem')); // assuming '#elem' is a TR/TD/TH node
```

Anyway, this is legacy API and you should be using `row().data()`, `rows().data()`, `cell().data()` API instead.

Check this: https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert